# Need help reading complex data in hive

Tags: hive

I've a data in file like

```
[street#226 S Wabash Ave,city#Chicago,state#IL]
[street#227 B H Tower,city#San Diego,state#CA]
```

I've created table using this code:

```
create external table if not exists test (
address map<string,string>
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\;'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
map keys terminated by '#'
;
```

but when I'm reading the file, I'm getting it parsed like this:

```
{"[street#939 W El Camino":null,"city#Chicago":null,"state#IL]":null}

{"[street#415 N Mary Ave":null,"city#Chicago":null,"state#IL]":null}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I first loaded the data as a string in the table and then created another table using 
`select str_to_map(regexp_replace(address,'\\[|\\]',''),',','#') as address from test;`